# Concat two strings to form an escape character in Java

Tags: java, string, char, escaping

I'm trying to read a file character by character and get escape characters interpreted as a single character (\b = '\b' instead of '\' + 'b').

I've performed the following experiment:

```java
System.out.println("\\" + 'b');
System.out.println("" + '\\' + 'b');
System.out.println('\b');
System.out.println("\b");
```

gives me

```
\b
\b
```

Any clues?
Thanks

Comment: escape symbols are processed at compile time, not runtime, what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: probably you need [unescapeJava](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava(java.lang.String)) - this will convert 2 char string "\b" into single char (code 7 I suppose)

Comment: @Iłya Bursov And can it be done without external API?

Comment: I am geting a diferent output for the last 2 lines. And the code for '\b' is 8.

Comment: @convert sure. get list of special symbols and write your own replacement

Comment: *"Any clues?"* -- Clues as to what?  The first two examples have a two-char string "backslash, lower-case letter b".  The second two examples have a one-char string "backspace".  This is nothing to do with reading or writing files, it is part of the rules for Java source code syntax.

Comment: @Iłya Bursov thanks for the link to the library but yeah I might just end up writing my own replacement. 

Wish there was a cool inbuilt way to do this but I guess this is a pretty specific use case

Comment: @Salmon The code you showed here has not much to do with reading files. Could you show you code for reading file character by character? Seeing that code would be more helpful to give you some solution.

Comment: @covert The question isn't really about reading files. The source of the chars could be from anywhere. It is more about concating 2 chars to form an escape character.